# 日本語分かち書きシステムを評価するためのライブラリはありますか？

Tags: 自然言語処理

日本語自然言語処理に興味を持つ中国の大学生です。最近はMeCabで形態素分析などのタスクを試しており、システムのパフォーマンスを評価する必要があります。自分でも評価するスクリプトを作成できると思うんですが、オープンソースライブラリがあればやはりマシになります。

Answer (score 1):

- [MeCab](https://taku910.github.io/mecab) に付属する `mecab-system-eval` というコマンド
- [MevAL](https://teru-oka-1933.github.io/meval/)

`mecab-system-eval` の使い方は書籍『形態素解析の理論と実装』（Mecab の作者、 工藤 拓 著）に軽く半ページほど触れられています。MevAL は `mecab-system-eval` より機能が多いようです。

Comment: コメントいただき、ありがとうございます！助かります！